# What does "Jedi Rocks" mean?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

In the 1997 Special Edition of *Return of the Jedi*, a musical number replaces Lapti Nek, known as "[Jedi Rocks](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Rocks)":

This is apparently its name both out of universe (it's listed as such on the [*Return of the Jedi* official soundtrack](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_VI:_Return_of_the_Jedi_(soundtrack)#Track_listing_for_the_Special_Edition_release)) and in universe (in Legends per the [*Complete Star Wars Encyclopedia*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Complete_Star_Wars_Encyclopedia#J); it may or may not be called that [in Canon](https://www.starwars.com/news/music-in-the-star-wars-galaxy-the-modal-nodes-vs-the-max-rebo-band)). I've always found it odd as a name, because it's not clear what it's referring to—is it in response to Luke's claim to be a Jedi Knight? (but then why say he "rocks"?) Is it saying *Return of the Jedi* is rocking out? (but then why is it called that in-universe?) Is it about [Geode](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Geode) or the [Iron Knights](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Knight)?

Here's all I could find on it in *Star Wars: The Annotated Screenplays*:

> *George Lucas:* "The scene in Jabba's Palace was supposed to have a big musical number, but unfortunately, we ended up with only a couple of shots. Now, thanks to digital technology, we're able to turn this scene into the real musical number that it was supposed to be in the first place. John Williams is doing a new score for the end music and felt it was okay to have someone else do the musical number because it is so different from the rest of the score."
>
> *Rick McCallum:* "We've added more musicians to the band; we have about eleven of them now. We have three backup singers, Sy Snootles moves like Mick Jagger, and there's an alien male singer next to her who sounds like Joe Cocker. We have a drummer with eight arms, a guitar player, etc. . . . The whole number is about two minutes now."
>
> <sub>(Source: [*Star Wars: The Annotated Screenplays*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Annotated_Screenplays), page 243)</sub>

Are there any official sources (Canon, Legends, or making-of) that explain what the name "Jedi Rocks" means?

Comment: As we know, being a Jedi is all about [making rocks float](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker#A_reluctant_teacher_and_enlightenment), so presumably the song title refers to rocks that mysterious seem to be lighter than air, like you'll feel when listening to this uplifting melody.

Comment: Jedis having kidney stones?

Comment: https://youtu.be/zzsAIZ2xzTU upbeat is equivalent to downbeat in all reference frames?

Comment: I don't see any indication on that starwars.com page that "Jedi Rocks" is an in-universe title.  Do you think the numbers played at the Mos Eisley cantina were called, in universe, "Cantina Band 1" and "Cantina Band 2"?

Comment: @Buzz Fair point - it was at least the in-universe name in Legends, according to the Complete Encyclopedia, but the article is less clear. I'll update the question.